# VSCode getResource cannot find the resource

Tags: java, image, path, bufferedimage

I am trying to load a Sprite file in to a game from a tutorial.

The tutorial is built in Eclipse and the person uses the IDE settings to add a resource folder allowing him to use getResource().

I am using VSCode, VSCode misses the .classpath path file in which the setting seems to of been placed. VSCode doesn't have a settings option for setting a Java Resource Directory.

I wish to be able to use getResource("directory/file.png")

I have tried adding a .classpath file and inputting the resources directory and results were the same.

I have tried loading it in different ways nothing is working.

```
package n0ngames.SandboxRPG.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet {
    private String path = null;
    public final int SIZE;

    public int[] pixels = null;

    public static SpriteSheet tiles = null;

    public SpriteSheet(String _path, int size) {
        this.path = _path;
        this.SIZE = size;
        this.pixels = new int[size * size];

        load();

        tiles = new SpriteSheet("C:/dev/SandboxRPG/res/textures/spritesheet.png", 256);
    }

    private void load() {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));
            int w = image.getWidth();
            int h = image.getHeight();

            image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, pixels, 0, w);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The offending line is this one `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResource(path));` the `getResource(path)` isn't working.

I would assume there is a way to get this line working as if VSCode couldn't it would be a large language feature missing form the Java language while using VSCode, so there must be a way.

Can anyone explain how to get this line to work correctly?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was to set the project up correctly.

**Step 1:** Press Ctrl + Shift + P

**Step 2:** Type Java

**Step 3:** Select Java: Create Java Project

**Step 4:** Name project

This will build a standard blank Java project for use.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem building 2d games in java. I couldn't find a way around. VSCODE settings are annoying. But finally I found this solution. I tried building a `netbeans` or `eclipse` for that matter. Then after that I coded using VSCODE and It worked just fine and now It is getting the resources.

---

For this case if you have already started coding on your project start a new project using `netbeans` or `eclipse` and copy paste configuration folders and files at the same relative location to your new project. Not a professional answer but it worked for me.

I copied:

- `nbproject` folder : copied the full folder into the vscode project. Then edited the files in it a little bit, not that much but things like names of project.
- `build.xml` file:
- `manifest.mf` file: